# Area of an Annulus (MeshTools<>NIntegrate)

Tags: numerical-integration, finite-element-method, mesh

**Fixed in Version 12.1.1**

In a very simple example I try to describe an annulus using  [MeshTools](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools) package

```
mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {    1 ,  2 }, {-Pi, Pi}, {36, 10}];
```

The area given by

```
{mesh2D["MeshElementMeasure"][[1]] // Total, Pi (2^2 - 1^2)} // N
(*{9.377, 9.42478}*)
```

differs significantly from evaluation of `NIntegrate` inside the element mesh

```
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, mesh2D]]
(*12.5027*)
```

What's wrong here?
Thanks!

Comment: Funny, it seems that `NIntegrate` thinks `Annulus` is a `Disk` in this case. If you create mesh for only half on annulus `AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {1,2}, {0,Pi}, {36,10}]` then the value of `NIntegrate` is ok.

Comment: @Pinti, this was the right clue.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann This bug is fixed in MeshTools 1.0.1 [release](https://github.com/c3m-labs/MeshTools/releases/tag/v1.0.1). Thank you for using this package!

Comment: @pinti Thanks, I'll update soon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Fixed in version 12.1.1**

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {-Pi, Pi}, {36, 10}];
NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, mesh2D]]
9.37700159401424`
```

**Old Answer:**

`AnnulusMesh` does not set the region hole of the mesh region. Then, in `NIntegrate` the mesh when the mesh is re-meshed that region hole is fully meshed.

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {-Pi, Pi}, {36, 10}];
mesh2D["RegionHoles"]
Automatic

SetRegionHoles[mesh2D, {{0, 0}}]
{{0.`, 0.`}}

NIntegrate[1, Element[{x, y}, mesh2D]]
9.37700159401424`
```

Note that an annulus meshed with `ToElementMesh` automatically sets that region hole property.

```
ToElementMesh[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]["RegionHoles"]
{{2.5326962749261384`*^-16, 2.7929047963226594`*^-16}}
```

I think the best way forward is to add a region hole to `AnnulusMesh`. I'll have a look how time consuming it would be for `NIntegrate` to auto search for region holes if the `mesh["RegionHoles"]` is Automatic; but that may be prohibitive.

In other words this is happening:

```
ToElementMesh[mesh2D]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

But you want this to happen:

```
ToElementMesh[mesh2D, "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0}}]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

The reason `NIntegrate` converts quad and hex meshes to triangle and tet meshes is that the main mechanism for `NIntegrate` is to do adaptive refinement which is only available for triangle and tet meshes. So for a quad or hex meshes an additional cost of conversion comes into play because we want this to work and give good results:

```
Needs["MeshTools`"]
mesh2D = AnnulusMesh[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {-Pi, Pi}, {36, 10}];
SetRegionHoles[mesh2D, {{0, 0}}];
nr = ToNumericalRegion[Annulus[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]];
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, mesh2D];
\[Pi] (2^2 - 1^1) - FEMNIntegrate[1, {x, y}, nr]
-6.6228668185175366`*^-6
```

Note, how the quality is much better than for the original annulus mesh. Probably the design of AnnulusMesh could be improved by allowing

```
AnnulusMesh[Annulus[{0,0},{1,2}],{-Pi,Pi},{36,10}]
```

Because then that same symbolic description used for the creation of an `AnnulusMesh` could be used to create the numerical region.

Comment: Thanks.That means , checking the mesh via mesh2D["Wireframe" ] is dangerous?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, no. This is only an issue in NIntegrate because it does remesh the structure you give it.

Comment: `mesh2D["Wireframe" ]`  before setting `RegionHoles` shows a plot with hole. That's what I tried to state in my last comment!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, nothing bad (dangerous) is going to happen when you look at the wire frame. Maybe you mean that the wire frame is misleading?

Comment: Yes, misleading, it shows an annulus!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann, the visualization just plots the elements present but the remeshing needs information if the inner boundary is an internal boundary or if it is a region hole. And that went missing.

Comment: @user21 Thanks for this clarification. I didn't know about this effect of `"RegionHoles"` on `NIntegrate`. I will fix this in MeshTools package immediately. But why does `NIntegrate` need to do internal remeshing if I pass it a nice `ElementMesh` anyway?

Comment: @Pinti, see update.

Comment: @Pinit, I just put in a fix. If a mesh has "RegionHoles" Automatic then the region hole computation is triggered. This would have avoided the issue seen here; but still I believe it is better to add "RegionHoles" explicitly to your mesh.

Comment: @user21 Thank you for all explanations. I have already updated MeshTools package with bugfix. In a near future I am going to add `"MeshOrder"->2` option for `AnnulusMesh` so its area can be computed with higher accuracy.